# How to choose MPI vendor/distribution with CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, mpi

I have a program that I would like to compile with CMake + make but using two different MPI distributions, OpenMPI and MPICH.

In Ubuntu, I have both installed; these are all the compiler wrappers I have installed:

```
mpic++           mpicxx           mpif77.mpich     mpijavac       
mpicc            mpicxx.mpich     mpif77.openmpi   mpijavac.pl    
mpiCC            mpicxx.openmpi   mpif90           mpirun         
mpicc.mpich      mpiexec          mpif90.mpich     mpirun.mpich   
mpicc.openmpi    mpiexec.hydra    mpif90.openmpi   mpirun.openmpi 
mpiCC.openmpi    mpiexec.mpich    mpifort          mpivars        
mpichversion     mpiexec.openmpi  mpifort.mpich                   
mpic++.openmpi   mpif77           mpifort.openmpi
```

(OpenMPI is the default, i.e. when no distribution extension is specified. I am not using modules.)

**How can I force CMake to choose MPICH over OpenMPI?**

I tried setting `-DMPI_ROOT=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich` but

<s>I get this error:</s>

```
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_WORKS) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_CXX_FOUND)

      Reason given by package: MPI component 'C' was requested, but language C is not enabled.  MPI component 'Fortran' was requested, but language Fortran is not enabled.  

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1721 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

it still uses OpenMPI.

This is how my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)
project(myproject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

#enable_language(C)  #uncommenting these doesn't help
#enable_language(Fortran)

enable_testing()
include(CTest)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `-DMPI_ROOT=` or `-DMPI_HOME=` didn't work for me. It still uses the default in my system (OpenMPI).

What worked was to set `-DMPI_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX=.mpich`, option which I found near the end of the documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html.

Answer (score 0):

Based on cmake [documents](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html), you should be able to select one by setting value of `MPI_GUESS_LIBRARY_NAME`.

**Update**: According to same document:

> Try to find an MPI implementation that does not ship such a wrapper by guessing settings. Currently, **only Microsoft MPI and MPICH2 on Windows are supported.**

Comment: According to the documentation, it suspiciously works with the string MPICH2 and MSMPI. In particular `-DMPI_GUESS_LIBRARY_NAME=MPICH2` didn't work for me. Maybe it works for a different setup.

Comment: @alfC my mistake. it seems guess library works only on windows. updated answer. you may be able to do it by setting `MPIEXEC_EXECUTABLE` manually, but not sure.

Comment: yes, or actually each of the compilers-wrappers as well. `mpiexec` is only part of the equation, this is the program that executes mpi-enabled programs.

Comment: How on earth does a build system need to "support" 3rd party products? In a makefile you'd set some variable with the include/link path and the name of the compiler and done. This is just silly. I can downloaded and compile MPI from source. How can a build system pre-emptively deal with that? Sorry, just venting about cmake.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I agree, the logic of some CMake procedures are “not even wrong”: I wouldn’t even know where to start criticizing them. On the other hand, the CMake point of view is that we have to be thankful that CMake at least ships with a FindMPI module. in a CMake perfect world, MPI libraries (distributions?) should ship with their corresponding CMake modules. Now since MPI is a standard in the first place, maybe that forces all distributions to agree on compatible CMake modules, may never happen. The CMake model naturally breaks down for “standards”: BLAS support is very convoluted too.

Comment: @alfC I'm willing to bet that cmake thinks that blas is a library that you need to link. Now use the Intel compiler suite, where a compiler flag `-mkl` is enough to get blas, lapack, fftw, and a bunch more. I like Make so much better.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Think of CMake as the thing that sets make’s “variable with include/link path and the name of the compiler” for you. (Also, for good or for bad, as the thing that writes the makefile for you.). Modules shipped with cmake do the best they can in a bunch of systems. it is great when it works. When it doesn’t, well, you are almost back to square one unfortunately.